# Displaying active navigation based on contextual data

Tags: java, spring, jsp, navigation, thymeleaf

I have the following separated fragment in a Thymeleaf template.

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/">Freight Invoices</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/processed">Processed Invoices</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/postingrules">Posting Rules</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to add an "active" class to active navigation element — but it seems hard to accomplish in Thymyleaf. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could add a **ModelAttribute** with the value *active* in your controllers for each page, e.g. :

*SettingsController.java*

```
@RequestMapping("/settings")
public String viewSettings(Model model) {
  // do stuff
  model.addAttribute("classActiveSettings","active");
  return "settings";
}
```

OR in a *SettingsControllerAdvice.java*

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = SettingsController.class)
public class SettingsControllerAdvice {

    @ModelAttribute("classActiveSettings")
    public String cssActivePage() {
        return "active";
    }

}
```

Then, in the navigation fragment included in your *settings.html* :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     <!-- Other links -->
    <li role="presentation" th:class="${classActiveSettings}">
       <a th:href="@{/settings}">Settings</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Finally, you can repeat this process for each controller and links in your navbar.

Comment: Can I add this in some kind of context processor etc? So I don't need to explicitly handle this?

Comment: I don't know, I never tried. But you can define this in a ControllerAdvice (method annotated with @ModelAttribute) ; it could be less ugly and more easy to update. I edit my post to give you this alternative.

Comment: If you do it this way (repeating the navigation everywhere), you could just hardcode it: `class="active"` and avoid any contoller setting.

Comment: Might aswell hardcode it as Stefan says. I have the nav menu as a fragment and it replaces the menu in several html pages. So this way is not possible. I must use another way like for example the one provided by Denger Tung.

Answer (score 84):

You can do this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/dashboard' ? 'active':''}"><a th:href="@{/dashboard}"><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
    <li th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/orders' ? 'active':''}"><a th:href="@{/orders}"><span>Orders</span></a></li>
    <li th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/income' ? 'active':''}"><a th:href="@{/income}"><span>Income</span></a></li>
    <li role="separator" ></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks something what I was looking for.

Comment: I prefer this to the accepted answer.   Better separation of concerns.  No need to clutter the server-side with things that are solely related to the view.

Comment: `#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI()` can be shortened to `#request.requestURI`.

Comment: Definitely a better answer than the accepted one. The controller shouldn't deal with classes of view elements.

Comment: Absolutely Brilliant.!

Comment: Thank you—a much better solution than the accepted answer.

Comment: ```#request.getServletPath()``` is more appropriate!

Comment: As of Spring Boot 3, you will receive an error trying to use this. Can someone update this answer for a Spring Boot 3 solution?

Answer (score 25):

Although i think it is ugly solution and it is pity that thymeleaf does not have some macros for it, you can use:

```
<li th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().startsWith('/hotels') ? 'active':''}">
    Hotel
</li>
```

It will work also for "deeper" links like */hotels/new* so it is usable also for multilevel menus.

Answer (score 14):

while this is an old question, I want to share this solution as it could be much more elegant!

http://nixmash.com/post/bootstrap-navbar-highlighting-in-thymeleaf

- Add a parameter (activeTab) to the navigation fragment.

```html
<div th:fragment="common-navbar(activeTab='activeTab')"></div>
```

- pass the value of it in the main pages that use the navbar fragment

```html
 <div th:replace="common/navbar :: common-navbar(about)"></div>
```

- check for it in the 'li' element to set the 'active' class

```html
 <li th:class="${activeTab == 'about'}? 'active' : null"><a href="">About</a></li>
```

Answer (score 3):

For those using Thymeleaf 3:

```
<a th:href="@{/home}" th:classappend="${#request.getRequestURI() == '/home' ? 'active' : ''}">Home</a>
```

If you have a context path on your application:

```
<a th:href="@{/home}" th:classappend="${#request.getRequestURI() == '/context-path/home' ? 'active' : ''}">Home</a>
```

**Edit:**

To be concise:

```
<a th:href="@{/home}" th:classappend="${#request.getServletPath() == '/home' ? 'active' : ''}">Home</a>
```

The benefit to using `request.getServletPath()` is that it ignores the context path, if there is one.

Answer (score 3):

In Thymeleaf 3.1.0+ you can provide the servlet path like this

`GlobalController.java`:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalController {

    @ModelAttribute("servletPath")
    String getRequestServletPath(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getServletPath();
    }
}
```

And then you can use ${servletPath} in your html file:

Example `navbar.html`:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" th:classappend="${servletPath == '/' ? 'active':''}" href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" th:classappend="${servletPath == '/parties' ? 'active':''}" href="/csv">Parties</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

Additional:
If you don't want to pass servletPath to all your endpoints, you need to pass it manually on all endpoints for the pages used in the navigation:

```java
// Endpoint for thymeleaf. Add the ServletPath
@GetMapping("/parties")
public String getPartiesPage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    model.addAttribute("servletPath", request.getServletPath());
    return "parties";
}

// Endpoint for other application. Don't add servletPath
@GetMapping(value = "/v1/parties/{id}", produces = "application/json;charset=utf-8")
public @ResponseBody PartyDto findBySystemOfRecordId(@PathVariable String id) {
    return partyService.findBySystemOfRecordId(id);
}
```

Comment: Great advice to use an advice for coping Thymeleafs abandoning of some former really usefuls utility objects.

Answer (score 0):

May be this code would be helpful for someone. Attention! It's not Thymeleaf solution, just js code which you can add on your pages.

```
var currentPage = location.href.match(/(.*?)([^\/]+)$/).pop();
        $(Array.prototype.filter.call($('.menu-head li a:nth-child(1)'), function(item)
        {
            return item.href.endsWith(currentPage)
        })).parents('li').addClass('active');
```