# Using th:classappend based on request param

Tags: thymeleaf

I have the following navigation using Thymeleaf and I want to append a CSS class when the link is selected:

```
<div class="nav-links">
    <a th:href="@{/somepage(someId=${someId},filter='filterA')}" href="/somepage"
    class="subnav-item"
    th:classappend="${selected}">Filter A</a>

    <a th:href="@{/somepage(someId=${someId},filter='filterB')}" href="/somepage"
    class="subnav-item"
    th:classappend="${selected}">Filter B</a>

    <a th:href="@{/somepage(someId=${someId},filter='filterC')}" href="/somepage"
    class="subnav-item"
    th:classappend="${selected}">Filter C</a>
</div>
```

Assuming some style like:

```
    .subnav-item.selected, .subnav-item.selected:hover, .subnav-item.selected:focus {
        background-color: #FFF;
        border-color: #000;
    }
```

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559817/thymeleaf-displaying-active-navigation-based-on-contextual-data), it can be easily done based on the URI of the page (in this case, `somepage` but I need to have it work selectively based on the request parameter (in this case, `filter`).  Is there an easy way to do this?

I tried adding the `selected` value to the model on the server side and separately tried using the request itself, but it does not differentiate based on the `filter` param (just on the `somepage` page).

Is the only way to do some hacky stuff with `request.getQueryString()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.  There's a utility for the `HttpServletRequest` that can easily be accessed as such:

`th:classappend="${#request.getParameter('filter') == 'filterA' ? 'selected' : ''}"`

Comment: for those still using thymeleaf 2.x, replace #request with #httpServletRequest

Comment: someone should really upgrade :)

Comment: ha! i did finally bite the bullet yesterday